# Series Convergence using Cauchy's test

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Trying to figure out if the following series converence:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)}{n^{n/2}}-\frac{n^{1/2}}{(n+1)}$$

I tried using Cauchy's test but it seems too complecated.

I'd appriciate if anyone has any idea!

Comment: The second term seems to make the sum diverge (the first term is very small very fast)

Comment: First of all am I right that series index is $n$ (instead of $k$) ?

Comment: ^yes! fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

so to me it seem that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n^\frac{n}{2}}-\frac{n^\frac{1}{2}}{n+1} \le 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}- \frac{n^\frac{1}{2}}{n+1}
\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} - \frac{n^\frac{1}{2}}{2(n+1)} \le 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} - \frac{n^\frac{1}{2}}{3n} $$
its since its clearly diverge to $ -\infty $ so dose to original series, i could explain why its diverge if you need me to but its quit easy

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}$$ is not well-defined.

Comment: good catch!, i have edited the answer so it will be more rigorous hopefully there are no mistake in the solution now

Comment: The inequalities are only true for some $n\ge N$.